# In Unix how can I count the number of times a string occurs in a certain number of lines and do multiplication with that return value

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to use something like 
     `` `expr 2 \\* grep -c ",2,1," my_course `` 
to try and multiply 2 by the number of lines that contain the String ",2,1," but I get a         `"expr: non-integer argument"` error. I'm new to Unix so can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The `grep ...` is interpreted as arguments to `expr`, which won't like that string of words a bit. You need to run grep and capture the output as an argument, like:

expr 2 \* $(grep -c ",2,1," my_course)

The `$(...)` runs the program inside, and makes what is returned into a list of strings.

(this with bash, other shells might need to use backquotes instead of `$(...)`)

Comment: im getting command not found errors... my line of code is temp= `'expr 2 \\* $(grep -c ",2,1," my_course)'`